# Can't get Dashing to display bar and line on same Rickshaw graph

Tags: javascript, rickshaw, dashing

I'm trying to use [this widget](https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023) to display 3 sets of data. the first set should be shown as a bar chart, and the rest can be displayed as lines on the chart.

From what I've read, Rickshaw Graphs should be able to do this by using the 'multi' renderer but I can't get that render to work at all.

Here is the ruby Array data object I'm sending, formatted to make it more readable:

```
iterationData:
    [
        {
            :name=>"Delivered", 
            :renderer=>"bar", 
            :data=> [
                {:x=>1, :y=>0}, 
                {:x=>2, :y=>4}, 
                {:x=>3, :y=>4}, 
                {:x=>4, :y=>11}
            ]
        }, 
        {
            :name=>"Estimated", 
            :renderer=>"line", 
            :data=> [
                {:x=>1, :y=>2.7}, 
                {:x=>2, :y=>5.4}, 
                {:x=>3, :y=>8.10}, 
                {:x=>4, :y=>10.8}, 
                {:x=>5, :y=>13.5}, 
                {:x=>6, :y=>16.2}, 
                {:x=>7, :y=>18.9}, 
                {:x=>8, :y=>21.59},
                {:x=>9, :y=>24.29}, 
                {:x=>10, :y=>26.99}
            ]
        }, 
        {
            :name=>"Outlook", 
            :renderer=>"line", 
            :data=> [
                {:x=>1, :y=>2.75}, 
                {:x=>2, :y=>5.5}, 
                {:x=>3, :y=>8.25}, 
                {:x=>4, :y=>11.0}, 
                {:x=>5, :y=>13.75}, 
                {:x=>6, :y=>16.5}, 
                {:x=>7, :y=>19.25}, 
                {:x=>8, :y=>22.0}, 
                {:x=>9, :y=>24.75}, 
                {:x=>10, :y=>27.5}
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and here is my calls to show the graph and to send data to the graph:

send_event in the ruby job:

```
send_event("#{projectID}-burnup-chart", {:series => iterationData})
```

dashboard.erb code:

```
<div data-id="23405488441-burnup-chart" data-view="Rickshawgraph" style="background-color:#ff9618" data-legend=true data-unstack=true data-renderer="bar" data-color-scheme="compliment" data-max="40"></div>
```

This just displays a blank widget with an orange background. The graph hasn't rendered at all. Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this? Or has anyone used a different widget to create a working burn up chart [like this](http://scrumage.com/wp-content/uploads/BurnUp.png) that they might be able to suggest?

Comment: Can you please provide the send-event line you're using in your Ruby job? The data you've pasted is not valid JSON -- it looks like Ruby output or something? Can you paste the output of hitting /events?

Comment: The object is a ruby object. Some of the data is pulled from a JSON call but the rest is generated with some basic math.

I'll add the send_event to the question for you. The result is a bit harder because i can't add pictures yet. Not enough rep.

If I try to use data-renderer:'multi' i just get an empty tile with no graph at all for the widget. if i use data-renderer:'bar' or 'line' it works fine, but doesn't look like what i'm after.

This question is more around if it's possible to display both lines and bars with this widget or not. (and if i'm doing something wrong to achieve it) :)

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're asking now. Don't worry about the JSON, but you could paste to something like pastie.org and then put a link here in the future. I've dug into the CoffeeScript code see how things are done and it was a special adventure in craziness. I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is impossible because of the way that this widget marshals parameters from Dashing to Rickshaw.

Specifically, these complicated lines of code:
https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023#file-rickshawgraph-coffee-L193-L253

I'm not sure if Rickshaw gets mad if you send it extra data, but the author of the widget seems very concerned about sending it incorrectly. Essentially, you are falling into this case:
https://gist.github.com/jwalton/6614023#file-rickshawgraph-coffee-L237-L245

You might be able to get it to work if you added a line to that `else if`, like this:

```
  else if series?.data?
  # Rickshaw data.  Need to clone, otherwise we could end up with multiple graphs sharing
  # the same data, and Rickshaw really doesn't like that.
  answer = {
    renderer: series.renderer  # add your renderer
    name:     series.name
    data:     series.data
    color:    series.color
    stroke:   series.stroke
  }
```

Or better yet, just use jQuery Extend to make a new copy:

```
answer = $.extend(true, {}, series);
```

Let me know how it goes and I'll update my answer to assist if further problems arise.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Unfortunately though, adding that one line to the rickshawgraph.coffee code seems to break the whole dashboard.

All my widgets stopped showing until i removed that line again.

I think you have answered the question though. With the widget provided it's not possible to display graphs using the 'multi' renderer. Unless I wanted to write a whole custom widget, which is far too much effort for me!

Thanks for your help. I've found a direct link to an existing graph that shows the data I'm after so i'm trying to show it using the Iframe widget instead :)